# Access data between two buttons in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, methods

my question is already in the title.Lets clarify this, Basically I made a simple program.In that program there are two buttons and a textbox one is for selecting a folder another for viewing it to textbox. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var filenames = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Example/Desktop/folder");

        }
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Lines = filenames

        }
```

but the filenames is underlined with red color.That means I cant access the "filenames" element from button2 can anyone tell me how to access it.Thanks

Comment: You can't access a *local* variable from a different method. But you could declare it as a field (`string[] filenames`) outside your first method, then just *assign* to it in the first method.

Comment: You need to define `filenames` outside the scope of your first button click event handler. You may want to read up some basics on [Variable and Method Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**filenames** array should be declared globally first to use inside click events of both buttons as said in comments. Also the we can't declare a variable with type var globally.

```
string[] filenames;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   filenames = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Example/Desktop/folder");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Lines = filenames
}
```

Comment: I think this answer requires some explanation

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, should be like this:

```
string[] filenames;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filenames = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Example/Desktop/folder");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Lines = filenames
}
```

*filenames* being an array of strings: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx).
Maybe it's good to read about scopes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

Comment: that'd give an error. you can not declare objects with var. you can only assign them. let me fix it.

Comment: @Doruk Ah yes! I didn't know it by heart so I included the link. Thanks for the fix

Answer (score 1):

You have declared and initialized the filenames variable inside the button1 click event handler method. Therefore, it can only be accessible inside that method (Scope). If you also need to access it from outside, then you need to declare the variable (in this case filenames) at the class level scope.

```
string[] filenames;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();            
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //var filenames = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Example/Desktop/folder");
    filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Users/Example/Desktop/folder");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Lines = filenames;
}
```

Recommended Readings...
[C# - Understanding Variable Scope](https://www.devu.com/tutorials/cs-asp/articles/lesson-24-understanding-variable-scope)
[C# Variable Scopes](https://tutorialstown.com/csharp-variable-scopes/)